# Правильно ли стоит запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

**Здесь же находится банк Cesare Ponti, где с удовольствием обменяют вашу валюту по выгодному курсу и с минимальной комиссией.**

Answer (score 1):

**Запятая стоит правильно**: Здесь же находится **банк Cesare Ponti**, где (в котором) с удовольствием обменяют вашу валюту по выгодному курсу и с минимальной комиссией.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным определительным, ГДЕ ― союзное слово.